# 0 - Class "Uri" not found

Tags: templates, joomla-4.x

I created Joomla template and tried to include a PHP script.

My index.php code:

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die; 
use Joomla\CMS\Uri\Uri;

?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Page</title>
<meta name="generator" content="WYSIWYG Web Builder 16 - http://www.wysiwygwebbuilder.com">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet">
<?php
//$myHeader = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/templates/".$this->template."/script/header.php";

$myHeader = JPATH_SITE."/templates/".$this->template."/script/header.php";
echo "<br>".$myHeader;
include $myHeader
?>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="FlexContainer1">
   </div>
   <div id="Layer1" style="position:fixed;text-align:center;left:0;top:0;right:0;height:142px;z-index:4;left:0px; width:100%">
      <div id="Layer1_Container" style="width:100%">
      </div>
   </div>
   <div id="FlexContainer2">
      <div id="wb_FlexContainer3">
         <div id="FlexContainer3" style="min-height:50px; ">
         </div>
      </div>
      <div id="FlexContainer4">
      </div>
      <div id="wb_FlexContainer5">
         <div id="FlexContainer5" style="min-height:50px;">
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` has a problem with the wrapper, so I commented it out. I surfed on the internet and found an article suggesting `JPATH_SITE`, but then I got a `0 - Class "Uri" not found` message. I surfed again and found information that I should use `use Joomla\CMS\Uri\Uri`, but the problem still remains.

this is my header.php codes

```
<?php
//defined('_JEXEC') or die; //sudah ada di wysiwyg head
//use Joomla\CMS\Uri\Uri; //sudah ada di wysiwyg head

$myjquery = Uri::root()."templates/".$this->template."/jquery-1.12.4.min.js";
$myIndexCss = Uri::root()."templates/".$this->template."/index.css";

?>
<jdoc:include type="head"/>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="media/system/css/joomla-fontawesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $myIndexCss ?>">

<script src="<?php echo $myjquery; ?>"></script>
```

I use these codes before and work fine but not through inclusion, I mean these codes were written directly into index.php

Comment: There is no use of `Uri` class in your posted snippet. Enable debug and inspect the stack trace to know where exactly it's used. Could be inside `header.php`.

Comment: Can you paste up the code in your  View class? If you put the use Joomla\CMS\Uri\Uri; before the class statement in your View you might resolve the issue. As @Sharky has said there is nothing in what you have pasted that appears to use URI, I suspect it is something in your View class.

Comment: I don't have any other files except these two files, `index.php`, and `header.php`, I wrote a `use Joomla\CMS\Uri\Uri`; as early as possible, as the first line must be `defined('_JEXEC') or die; `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Symbol imports using `use` statement are file-scoped (except when using inside namespace blocks). Which means you have to import them in the file where it's used. So you have to move `use Joomla\CMS\Uri\Uri;` statement from `index.php` to `header.php`.